# NodeJS server results in timeout

Tags: node.js, timeout

I have a NodeJS server script, which works like a charm on my local dev environment. But in (beta) production the webserver times out at every request. I've set this up fairly straight forward but I'm unsure how to fix it - or even where to look for a solution. Below is a simplified implementation, my logic for handling post request has been removed. What am I overlooking?

```
var requestListener = '';
// define the request listener, to handle incoming requests
requestListener = function (req, res) {
    try {
        if (req.method == 'POST') {
            var queryString = '';
            req.on('data', function (data) {
                queryString += data;
            });
            req.on('end', function () {
                // my logic is in here
                res.end(JSON.stringify({ err: false, msg: 'all fine' }));
            });
        }

        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end();
    } catch (error) {
        res.writeHead(400);
        res.end(error);
    }
}

// boot the webserver
server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Does it time out for GET requests as well?

Comment: Yes, if I access the https://subdomain.domain.com:8080/main.js I get the time out too.

Comment: Can you ping the server?

Comment: Not sure about the timeout, but this code has other problems.  It will `res.writeHead(200)` and `res.end()` for all incoming requests, even your POST because `req.on('data', ....)` and `req.on('end', ...)` are just event listeners.  They don't block code flow so the code will flow through to after that block for all incoming requests.  So, even if it didn't timeout (for some other reason), it still wouldn't work properly as written.

Comment: Where are you running the server?  Where are you making the request from?  Is there a firewall in the way?   Does it work if you use `http://localhost:8080` from the same host?

Comment: I can't ping to `ping subdomain.domain.com:8080/main.js`, it says it can't resolve the hostname. Pinging to the domain works, but that doesn't ping my nodejs script. Firewall might be interesting to check, will do that.

Comment: It was indeed a firewall issue. Thanks and should imprint that time-outs relate to firewalls (not the first time this is a solution to a likewise issue). Have a nice day!

Comment: Use express.js rather than try to do this on your own. It's battle harden and very easy to use.